FBX export distortion
Blender 4.1.1
Plugins: Rokoko and Rigify
Hi there, I'm pretty desperate since I've spent weeks trying to make these FBX exports work, so I'm looking for more help. I'm coming from a maya background, so I may not be the best at blender.
Anyway, I'm trying to export these FBX animations that were created with some mixamo data attached with the rokoko plugin. The rig wasn't created by me, for context, this was created by our tech artist. But, while the animation works perfectly fine in blender, there's some distortion going on when exporting to FBX. I notice specifically that the bones start bending backwards, so his spine isn't aligned as it should be I believe.
Here's a link to the original file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FqTMUWpqv7s5SqdK828IwETcUISRmzL_/view?usp=drive_link
Absolutely any help is appreciated. I did fix the stretch to constraint on all the deformation bones as suggested on someone else's forum post, and it fixed the problem a bit when I turned maintain volume to "none" but it didn't fully solve the problem.




Your file is in restricted access. I see in your export option that you enabled Bake Animation. Is the screenshot of your stretched character in default pose or from an animation?

Also there might be addons that can help with this. Rigify is known to not be game-engine ready out of the box, afaik there are quite a few steps you could need to take (removing bendy bones, stretch constraints, other constraints, drivers, cleaning deformation bones, ...) So it's not that surprising that people propose automated solutions. I've heard at least two: Game Rig Tools (pay what you want) and Uefy 2.0 (paid)
